# Merge following portions of lines into current line in a 3 column file

Tags: awk, sed, text, join

I have a text file with format `word @@@ type @@@ sentence` on every line, sorted by 'word' in ascending order.  Some lines however are not unique and they begin with the same word as the previous line, ie see word1 below:

```
...
word0 @@@ type2 @@@ sentence0
word1 @@@ type1 @@@ sentence1
word1 @@@ type1 @@@ sentence2
word1 @@@ type1 @@@ sentence3
word1 @@@ type2 @@@ sentence4
word2 @@@ type1 @@@ sentence5
...
```

I want to join the lines that have the same word and type combination into one, by appending the sentences, so the file results in:

```
...
word0 @@@ type2 @@@ sentence0
word1 @@@ type1 @@@ sentence1 ;;; sentence2 ;;; sentence3
word1 @@@ type2 @@@ sentence4
word2 @@@ type1 @@@ sentence5
...
```

The word and type fields have no whitespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your input is sorted on both `word` and `type` fields as it appears from your posted sample input:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=" @@@ "; ORS="" }
{ curr = $1 FS $2 }
curr != prev {
    printf "%s%s", ORS, $0
    prev = curr
    ORS = RS
    next
}
{ printf " ;;; %s", $NF }
END { print "" }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
word0 @@@ type2 @@@ sentence0
word1 @@@ type1 @@@ sentence1 ;;; sentence2 ;;; sentence3
word1 @@@ type2 @@@ sentence4
word2 @@@ type1 @@@ sentence5
```

The above will work using any awk in any shell on every UNIX box, only stores 1 line at a time in memory, and will produce output in the same order as the input.

Comment: I would never have been able to come up with this - Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way, in awk:

```
$ awk -F'@@@' '{ $1 in a ? a[$1][$2]=a[$1][$2]" ;;; "$3 : a[$1][$2]=$3}END{for(word in a){for (type in a[word]){print word,FS,type,FS,a[word][type]} }}' file 
word0  @@@  type2  @@@  sentence0
word1  @@@  type1  @@@  sentence1 ;;;  sentence2 ;;;  sentence3
word1  @@@  type2  @@@  ;;;  sentence4
word2  @@@  type1  @@@  sentence5
```

Or, a bit more legibly:

```
awk -F'@@@' '{ 
                if($1 in a){ 
                    a[$1][$2]=a[$1][$2]" ;;; "$3
                }
                else{
                    a[$1][$2]=$3
                }
             }
             END{
                 for(word in a){
                     for (type in a[word]){
                         print word,FS,type,FS,a[word][type]
                     }
                 }
             }' file
```

---

Note that this requires an `awk` implementation that understand multidimensional arrays, such as GNU awk (`gawk`), which is the default `awk` on Linux systems.

Comment: That's not producing the expected output (see the 3rd line of output for an extra `;;;` and there's extra blanks after all the `;;;`s). Also you should mention that the use of `for ... in` will shuffle the order of the output and the script stores the whole file in memory.